# How to use threading when calling a method of a service using binders

Tags: java, android, multithreading, binding, service

I Have a Service and i interact with it from an activity using "Binding".

Now, some of these methods that i've exposed to be called using binding, may take some time to complete (heavyweight).

How can run this in a seperate thread?

Should i, use threading in the "Activity" or in the "Service" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if your task should be completed anyway (even if Activity is stoped) or if you need thread, that will listen for server updates, use Service. Else, use Activity.

Now you can do your task in background using these ways (in `Activity` or `Service` - it doesn't matter):

1) Best way is to start [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

2) Other way is to start Thread:

```
public void someServiceMethod(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //do your stuff
            }
        }
    ).start();
}
```

And read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Answer (score 2):

> How can run this in a seperate thread?

By forking a thread, or using an `AsyncTask`, etc.

> Should i, use threading in the "Activity" or in the "Service" ?

That is up to you and cannot be answered in the abstract.